# how to make top bar responsive in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

am stuck with problem am trying to create a top bar , its properly working on desktop mode , but when am trying to view on mobile view its not responsive a want to make it responsive,
can anyone fix for me

my mobile view is

[image]

i want like this in mobile view

[image]

> header.html

This is my top-bar page where I wrote my all code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Header</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
        <div class="row top-bar">
            <div class="col p-3">
                <span class="text-white">
                    Offer Zone Top Deal & Discounts <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col "></div>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i> Select Location
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                |
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                <i class="fas fa-truck-moving"></i> Track Order
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                |
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> 012 345 6789
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                |
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Log In
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                |
            </span>
            <span class="text-white p-3">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Register
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try Using:

`<ul class="navbar-nav">`
`<li class="nav-item">`
`<span class="text-white">`
Offer Zone Top Deal & Discounts `<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">`   `